# Is there any better way to improve my formula?

Tags: excel-formula

So I am using SharePoint online sheets and I have a formula which uses the below formula to pull a specific sheet.
The objective was to pull the latest data from an external sheet.

```
IFS(AND(TEXT(TODAY(), “MMMM”)=“March”, TEXT(TODAY(), “YYYY”)=“2021”),’url’[file]March 2021’$A$3
```

So at the moment I am creating a master sheet where this formula resides, the formula is essentially a data dump of a specific file containing sheets with name “Month Year” being the respective month and year. Essentially a full workbook would contain January to December of 2021.

Right now I am thinking of querying each file specifically due to being unable to use a cell reference in my external file call.

I want to know if there is a better way than having to call each sheet specifically to conditions using IFS? It would be a long formula.

Comment: It's not clear what the objective of IFS is in this context. e.g. you could do: `=INDIRECT("’url’[file]"&TEXT( TODAY(),"MMMM" )&" "&TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYY")&"’$A$3")` and get a filename that matches today's month if it exists, but that might not be the "latest". It would seem that an IFS would search many available sheets and determine which is the latest. Is that really the objective? Perhaps you can describe the external workbooks/sheets.

Comment: I have I will update further

Comment: I will have to try this I had trouble using indirect when trying to call sheets from a workbook using dynamic names.

Comment: I have attempted to use this formula however I get a reference error.

Comment: I don't have access to an SP server, but I am realizing that INDIRECT will only work if the target workbook is open. The other way to achieve what you want would be to use Power Query which will open the target folder and the workbooks inside so that the data can be exposed. Will that work for you?

Comment: If the solution is within the capabilities of Excel Online then yes that would be helpful. Otherwise is it possible to use variable names within the formula, Everytime i have tried using a cell reference for the name i come up with an error.